# Using InfoPath forms with a custom SharePoint 2013 workflow designed in Visual Studio

Tags: 2013, workflow, infopath, workflow2013

The "stock" SharePoint approval workflow comes with custom InfoPath forms that enable a nice "Open this task..." button in Outlook that displays an approval form right in the Outlook.

However if I design a custom approval workflow in Visual Studio 2015, I cannot get anything like that; the CombinedTask activity does not seem to expose any properties that would allow associating the task with any custom forms.

Having done some googling, I came to realize that I would need to create custom InfoPath forms from scratch and link them to the workflow tasks somehow, but I haven't been able to find any reasonable tutorials on how this could be achieved in SharePoint 2013.

The only relevant post I was able to find was this: [Custom Task Forms created in InfoPath for Visual Studio Workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33124/custom-task-forms-created-in-infopath-for-visual-studio-workflow) but that one was for SharePoint 2010.

Does the content of that post still apply to SharePoint 2013 (barring the version numbers and things like that), or should I approach this at a completely different angle? At the first glance, the described approach uses some C# code which automatically makes it not applicable for a SharePoint-hosted add-in scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the described approach uses some C# code which automatically makes it not applicable for a SharePoint-hosted add-in scenario, you should also know that the Workflow 2013 Task form has been changed from `InfoPath form` to **ASPX form**, as mentioned in SharePoint Designer section at [SharePoint Server 2013 known issues](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Server-2013-known-issues-780242a6-236e-4d7a-8379-118a1aaa2a51?CorrelationId=f7b0b3a3-f817-49d6-bb02-6457b71f5e98&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102919021#__sharepoint_designer_1)

So I don't think the mentioned article is valid in your case!